# Statsmodels OLS p value comparison inside if statement does not work

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, statsmodels

I have a dataset where I want to run pairwise regression (with a fixed independend variable, and all other variables are looped in a for loop as dependent variables), extract p values, and if a p value is lower than 0.05 print that.

I was able to run the statsmodels.OLS and get the p value with a float64 dtype, but when I use it in an if statement, it returns True even when its false.

```
for column in my_patients_volbrain_volumes:
  if my_patients_volbrain_volumes[column].name=="Sex":
    pass
  else:
    X=my_patients_volbrain_volumes['3rd Ventricle volume cm3']
    Y=my_patients_volbrain_volumes[column]
    model = sm.OLS(X,Y)
    result = model.fit()

    if result.pvalues[0]<0.05:
      print(my_patients_volbrain_volumes[column].name)
      print(result.pvalues[0])
      print(result.params[0])
```

I also tried other things, including multiplying the result.pvalues[0] with 100, and it seems it does not multiply either.

Comment: what does `type(result.pvalues[0])` and `result.pvalues[0]` give you if you print it?

Comment: the type is numpy.float64 and resul.pvalues[0]  seems to be a number.

I tried changing the type to decimal, bu that had no effect. The number actually does not behave like a number at all. most of the p values are in 2.123123 format, when I try to change the dtype to int, they turn into 0.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Are you sure this piece of code prints any pvalues[0] >= 0.05 ?

Comment: doing regressions in a loop and comparing against that hard threshold looks problematic, might be worth reading about the [multiple comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).  this is one of the issues behind the reproducibility crisis

Comment: the example at the top of https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html looks very similar to your code, does it exhibit the same issue?  might be worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SamMason Thank you very much, It was a great read. It was great to learn about this problem.